# Kibana: why the result changes when I query more by specific order?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

My first query is to ask the first 5 result which descends by a unique count of a field:

[image]

My second query, everything remains the same, just change 5 to 50:

[image]

That result surprised me. In my expectation, the first 5 result will remain the same and just display 45 more results in the second query. I just got confused, and could anyone give me some hints?

Comment: This is because document counts are approximate, you'll find a good explanation and example here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-approximate-counts If you had a single shard in your index, you'd not see this problem.

Comment: @Val Really thanks!